# How do I make a HTML table to be bigger than the default page size

Tags: html

I have a table made with HTML and PHP (PHP for the content) and because of the length of some of the sentences in one of the sub-sections I need the width to go outside the screen(so scrolling goes in width as well as height).

The printed text in one of the columns is a full stack trace for an Android app and because of the short length of the column, the text gets 'squeezed' inside it.

How can I expand the table in width to go off the screen so a scrollbar at the bottom appears? I'm going to add another column too so I need to have space enough.

Additionally, because of the height of the text in one of the 6 columns the other content gets set to the middle of the column. How do I make all the text start at the top independently of the other columns?

Important code:

```
<table border="1" style="border:2px solid black;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>time</td>
            <td>android_version</td>
            <td>device_id</td>
            <td>app_version</td>
            <td>stacktrace</td>
            <td>package</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            //etc database stuff
           while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['time'];?></td>
                <td ><?php echo $row['android_version'];?></td>
                <td ><?php echo $row['device_id'];?></td>
                <td ><?php echo $row['app_version'];?></td>
                <td ><?php echo $row['stacktrace'];?></td><!-- This is the part that is very long. The other text is centered based on the length of this. -->
                <td><?php echo $row['package'];?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried searching for it, but I only found questions relating to tables going outside the default visible screen but they did not want it. I want the table to be its full size, even if the screen expands so there is a scrollbar in width

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make table width bigger you can apply some CSS for StackTrace column.

If you need to display it in one line - use `white-space: nowrap;`
If you need only some specific width for it - use `min-width: #px` or just `width: #px;`

To align all elements to top of cell use `vertical-align: top`.

```css
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
td:nth-child(5) {
  /*white-space: nowrap;*/
  min-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" style="border:2px solid black;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>time</td>
      <td>android_version</td>
      <td>device_id</td>
      <td>app_version</td>
      <td>stacktrace</td>
      <td>package</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>

      <td>1975-01-01
        <br/>1975-01-01
        <br/>1975-01-01</td>
      <td>5.3</td>
      <td>9/11</td>
      <td>0.1.001</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi nec tortor vitae augue tempus egestas. Maecenas dictum dui vitae nisl tempus porta. Fusce ac nunc nec magna gravida sodales eget sed massa. Integer dapibus pulvinar tortor, ut ultrices
        nulla convallis vitae. Aenean egestas nunc sem, et efficitur est viverra at. Curabitur ipsum ante, commodo ac facilisis vitae, lobortis vitae felis. Curabitur dapibus faucibus erat, vitae consectetur est. Proin rutrum purus vel massa faucibus
        elementum. Vivamus venenatis a ante nec fringilla. Phasellus volutpat eu erat et placerat. Quisque diam felis, mollis vel auctor et, dapibus sed nisi. Maecenas vitae nisi leo. Proin aliquam malesuada nisl, sed imperdiet ligula porta non.</td>
      <td>Nop!</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

*Note*

I see that you are using `mysql_fetch_assoc` -- **Don't use *deprecated* functions**! Use PDO or MySqli

Comment: It took very long to set up everything with MySQL. I'm using PHP 5.6  and it will cause a lot of problems upgrading it to MySQLi. But thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

To your question:

> How do I make all the text start at the top independantly of the other columns?

You must set a vertical align (`vertical-align` in CSS, or `valign` in  HTML):

```
<td valign="top">
```

OR

```
<td style="vertical-align: top">
```

Answer (score -1):

> How do I make a HTML table to be bigger than the default page size

You can give `width` more than `100%`

```css
td {vertical-align: top;}
```

```html
<body>
        <table border="1" style="border:2px solid black;width: 150%;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>time</td>
                    <td>android_version</td>
                    <td>device_id</td>
                    <td>app_version</td>
                    <td>stacktrace</td>
                    <td>package</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php

                //etc database stuff

                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
               ?>

                    <tr>

                        <td><?php echo $row['time'];?></td>
                        <td ><?php echo $row['android_version'];?></td>
                        <td ><?php echo $row['device_id'];?></td>
                        <td >some text</td>
                        <td >This is the part that is very long. The other text is centered based on the length of this.</td> 
                        <td ><?php echo $row['package'];?></td>

                    </tr>

                <?php
                }



                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: I did that exact same thing with width in the exact same location and way first. Nothing changed.